# ASP.NET two databases in one web control?

Tags: asp.net, database, controls

I have a database with two different tables, connected with one to many relationship. I would like to present values from table one together with fields refering to it from table two. I was trying to experiment with gridview and repeater control but did not manage to achieve any major success. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code will help a lot.
without it there is basically two options what you can do

first and fairly simple is to do one query to both tables, bind it to Sql DataSource and bind gridview or listview or other control bindable to enumerable.

ie

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="productDataSource" Runat="server" 
     SelectCommand="select t1.f1, t1.f2, ..... , t2.f1, t2.f2, ... from t1 inner join t2 on ..."
    ConnectionString="your connection string">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="productsGridView" Runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="productDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></asp:GridView>
```

another (probably the right way to do it) is to adopt master detail scenario using two grid views for instance. you can find good example [here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs)

Comment: Yep, this is how I will probably finally do it. I will create a selectable gridview for table one which will be presenting related values from table two in details view.